# Bridge network interfering with some Intranet domains

Tags: networking, network-interface, vmware, bridge

I have some bridge networks which I don't know where they come from:

```
$ ifconfig | grep -o "^br-\w*"
br-4e3069271b9c
br-919ad27f74b2
br-e448c7cbb558
br-e6840866c3b6
br-636926a06053
```

(I suspect either docker, vmware or virtualbox which are installed).

The problem is, these bridge networks are somehow interfering with *some* intranet addresses, while *other* intranet addresses still work:

```
$ ping some.intranet.tld
From 172.21.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.21.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.21.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

$ ifconfig | grep -C 1 "172.21.0.1"
br-636926a06053 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:af:36:20:65  
inet addr:172.21.0.1  Bcast:172.21.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

After issuing `sudo ifconfig br-636926a06053 down` everything works again.

```
PING some.intranet.tld (12.23.45.67) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from some.intranet.tld (12.23.45.67): icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=11.7 ms
```

---

But the problem appears again after restart and also I'm not sure if there are any negative side-effects shutting down that connection.

**How to <strike>find out which program starts these bridge networks and how to</strike> eliminate the issue ?**

---

---

**Update**:

It seems these bridges are coming from **vmware**:

```
$ sudo grep br-636926a06053 /var/log/syslog.1
Aug  7 08:58:56 hostname vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK: name:br-636926a06053 index:7 flags:0x00001002
Aug  7 08:58:56 hostname vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK: name:br-636926a06053 index:7 flags:0x00001002
Aug  7 08:58:56 hostname NetworkManager[1212]: <info>  [1533625136.8516] manager: (br-636926a06053): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most certainly Docker. VMware only detects them appearing (eg: to have them displayed in the GUI or perhaps to alter some networking rules (natd?)) as would the command `ip monitor link` in real time.

In [`docker network create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#connect-containers) it's hinted this:

> Specify advanced options
>
> When you create a network, **Engine creates a non-overlapping
>   subnetwork for the network by default. This subnetwork is not a
>   subdivision of an existing network. It is purely for ip-addressing
>   purposes.** You can override this default and specify subnetwork
>   values directly using the --subnet option. On a bridge network you can
>   only create a single subnet:
>
> ```
> $ docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.0.0/16 br0
> ```

What is not written is that the default choice starts from `172.17.0.0/16` and each subsequent network moves on up to `172.31.0.0/16` if not told otherwise. I couldn't find it explicitely, but most examples show that newly created bridges are all `/16` part of `172.16.0.0/12`, for example: in [`Multiple Docker Networks`](https://success.docker.com/article/multiple-docker-networks) with no explicit `--subnet` the two subnets `172.29.0.0/16` and `172.30.0.0/16` are created. I'd be glad to add a definite reference to the default behaviour if provided.

To eliminate the issue, you should check what automated part in Docker (perhaps itself a privileged container etc.) creates those networks (you have logs on when they are activated as an interface, that may not be when they were initially created in the Docker configuration, but a simple `docker network ls` should confirm all this), and how to change their default network settings. I'm sure there are more radical methods, eg creating a network to reserve so Docker won't create the same, then keep it down, either by a Docker method if available, or like you did `ip link set br-somenetworkid down`.

Comment: @pLumo just noticing you're around but never commented on this answer